# Why does setting a border give an element 1px extra internal height?

Tags: css

When putting a border around a block element, **why does the apparent visual height of the element *inside* the border increase by 1**? The reported `offsetHeight` is still equal to the desired height plus the border widths.

This becomes problematic when trying to make an inner block element the same height as an outer element. Notice the extra 1px of height the outer element has in this example, causing the inner element's background color to not fill the entire container:

```css
#outer { height: 10px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid red; }
#inner { height: 10px; width: 50%; background-color: black; }
/* Setting #inner height to 100% has the same problem. */
```

```html
<div id="outer"><div id="inner"></div></div>
```

On my device, there's a one-pixel-high gap between the black background and the red border.

[image: repro showing 1px gap above border]

What causes this, and how can I remove the "extra" bit of height inside the outer element so that my inner element takes up the full visual height of its container?

Does this have something to do with subpixel rendering?

**Edit**: This question is not about the box model per se. I do understand the box model; the problem here is that the element is being rendered with extra height *inside* its borders. Even Chrome's dev inspector doesn't show this "extra" height in its box model, but it's apparent on the screen.

Comment: Take a look at this article. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model you will discover what's happening ;) down here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model#the_standard_css_box_model

Comment: Heh, thanks, but I'm a software engineer on Chrome -- I understand the box model. This question is about the one-pixel gap introduced when a box is given a border. Even a zero-height box has a visual inner height of one pixel (its background actually becomes visible!) when given a border, which just seems wrong. I think it has to do with display density.

Comment: hello,  i see now what you mean from the screenshot you added . On my computer , there is no gap either FF or webkit, on my android, samsung shows a gap all around, android FF, no gaps , android Chrome , a gap all around. .:(

Answer (score 0):

It's because default [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) of element is `content-box` meaning `width` and `height` will be applied only to element content box.

Setting it to `border-box` will include border into `width` and `height` too

```css
#without,
#with {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

#without .inner {
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid green;
    background: yellow;
}

#with .inner {
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid green;
    background: yellow;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="without">
  <div class="inner">Without</div>
</div>

<div id="with">
  <div class="inner">With</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, my question isn't about the border width not being included in the box's height -- it's about the *existence* of a border resulting in an incorrectly rendered inner height.

Comment: If you are talking about that 1px gap in image below black bar: It's not reproducible in your example code, so it's either something else there (e.g. elements are displayed inline and there is whitespace character; `:after` element) or browser rendering issues (that I have never faced)

Comment: Gotcha. It seems to only happen on my Chromebook, which scales the display output. If I zoom it out to the native resolution, the gap goes away.

Comment: @mgiuffrida So you can close your question, because then it's your specific browser setup issue and not code

Comment: sure, if you can show me what the spec says about high-density device rendering in this situation :-\

Answer (score -1):

Browsers calculate sizes starting on the content then add `padding` and `border` (except IE but that's another story).

You can now changes `box-sizing` to tell the browser when you say `width: 100px` you mean "I want 100px border to border".

```css
.outer { height: 50px; border: 10px solid red; }
.inner { height: 50px; width: 50%; background-color: black; }

.border * { box-sizing: border-box; }
.content * { box-sizing: content-box; }

.border, .content {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Content based</p>
<div class="content">
  <div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
</div>
<p>Border based</p>
<div class="border">
  <div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
</div>
```

With `box-sizing: border-box` and both `div` with the same height, the `inner` one must overflow the `outer`

Comment: Adjusting box-sizing doesn't affect the repro case in my question. Please take a look at my code snippet; this question isn't about box-sizing. Regardless of the offsetHeight of the element, an inner element with height: 100% ought to span the entire content height of the outer element, but specifically on a high-density display it doesn't.